# not redirecting to NotAuthorized Page - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following app.routes.ts

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '../app/components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/components/login/login.component';
import { LoggedInGuard } from '../app/logged-in.guard';
import { CategoriesComponent} from '../app/components/categories/categories.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from '../app/components/logout/logout.component';
import { RegisterComponent} from '../app/components/register/register.component';
import { NotAuthorizedComponent} from '../app/components/not-authorized/not-authorized.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
    {path: 'notAuthorized', component: NotAuthorizedComponent},
    {path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
    {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and then I have a categories.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Categories} from '../Categories';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
  apiUrl: string;
  categories: Categories[] = [];

  constructor(private _http:Http, private router:Router) { 
    this.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:50424/api/';
  }

  getCategories() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

    return this._http.get(this.apiUrl+ 'Categories/Get', { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
      .map(this.extractObject)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

   private extractObject(res: Response): Categories {
    let categories = res.json();
    return categories || { };
  }

   private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
        console.log('We have an unathorized request');
        //handle authorization errors
        this.router.navigate(['notAuthorized']);
      }

    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

which is basically getting some categories from an API.  All works well, however I want to limit this for only authorized users.  So when throwing a server error 401 or 403, I want to redirect the user to a NonAuthorized page. My code is getting to the

```
console.log('We have an unathorized request');
```

correctly, however it is not doing the redirection, and staying on the same page.  What I can do to redirect the user to another "NonAuthorized" page?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is the issue, but this [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#navigate) suggests that you need to use `this.router.navigate(['/notAuthorized']);`

Comment: I have already tried that but does not work, still on the same page!

Comment: I also tried this.router.navigate(['']); but does not take me to the home page neither

Comment: I guess this behavior is correct, because your home page is guarded?

Comment: it should throw an error though.  I noticed that the this.router is undefined in that function, how can I pass it from the getCategories() function?

Comment: This seems to be a scope issue. I think you need to pass `this.router` to your `handleError` method.

Comment: that is what I think also, however I have tried to pass it with no good results.  I tried       .catch(this.handleError(this.router)); and then    private handleError (error: any, router:Router) {} does not work

Comment: You could try this: `.catch(error => this.handleError(error, this.router))`

Comment: Perfect that solved my problem!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can I add this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is a scope issue, since `this.router` is not known in the scope of the passed `this.handleError`. Therefore the signature needs to be changed to `private handleError(error: any, router: Router)` and the corresponding call in the subscription will be `.catch(error => this.handleError(error, this.router))`